# How to set a column width in .h and .cpp files in emacs?

Tags: emacs

I want to have text-width to 80 columns for .h and .cpp files in emacs.
What I tried is following,

**M-x auto-fill-mode 
C-x f**

But above solution is not working.

Also I tried the solution present at http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CPlusPlusMode. It is as below.

```
; style I want to use in c++ mode                                                                                                                                                                                 
(c-add-style "my-style"
  '("stroustrup"
      (indent-tabs-mode . nil)        ; use spaces rather than tabs                                                                                                                                          
      (c-basic-offset . 4)            ; indent by four spaces                                                                                                                                                
      (c-offsets-alist . ((inline-open . 0)  ; custom indentation rules                                                                                                                                      
      (brace-list-open . 0)
      (statement-case-open . +)))))

(defun my-c++-mode-hook ()
(c-set-style "my-style")        ; use my-style defined above                                                                                                                                                   
(auto-fill-mode)
(c-toggle-auto-hungry-state 1))
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'my-c++-mode-hook)**
```

Though, I did not completely understand the solution provided at emacswiki. 
Appreciate any help in this regard.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `fill-column` only in those modes, which you can do by defining a function to do so and adding that hook to the relevant modes (you could also do it as a `lambda`, but it's usually good practice to put it in a named function so you can remove it from the hook later if you need to).  `*.h` files come up in `c-mode` by default, while `*.cpp` files come up in `c++-mode` by default.  First, define a function:

```
(defun my-c-hook ()
  (setq fill-column 80))
```

Then, add that function to the relevant mode hooks:

```
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'my-c-hook)
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'my-c-hook)
```

You can make your function as rich as you like, eg, by putting in the other items you had originally:

```
(defun my-c-hook ()
  (c-set-style "my-style")
  (auto-fill-mode)
  (c-toggle-auto-hungry-state 1)
  (setq fill-column 80))
```