# How to insert Soft/Hard returns after line reaches fill-column value?

Tags: emacs

As per Dan's suggestion at [How to set a column width in .h and .cpp files in emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25089658/how-to-set-a-column-width-in-h-and-cpp-files-in-emacs), I have added following function for fill-column after column 80

```
(defun my-filcol-hook ()
  (setq fill-column 80))
```

And I added this as a hook to C-mode and C++-mode. This works fine but when I enhanced it to insert a SOFT return by turning on longlines mode, emacs hangs on a file with 15000 .cpp file. It works fine for files smaller in size(I tried till 3000). Below is how my c-mode and C++ mode hook looks like,

```
(defun my-filcol-hook ()
  (longlines-mode t)
  (setq fill-column 80))
```

Is there any alternative to longlines-mode, which will work even on bigger files?

Comment: Check out [visual-line-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/VisualLineMode).  It looks like others have noted that `longlines-mode` has [problems with large buffers](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2009-05/msg00642.html).

Comment: Thanks. I tried the solution of JamesWright shown given at [link](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/VisualLineMode ) and added exact code mentioned on emacswiki but it did work.(Did not enter hard or soft return at column-width 80)

Comment: With visual-line-mode, it would be necessary to rely upon the window-width (less margins and fringes) -- not the fill-column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`visual-line-mode` normally wraps at the window border, as @lawlist's comment suggests.  However, if you use the code that [James Wright](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/JamesWright) posted to [the EmacsWiki for Visual Line Mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/VisualLineMode) and enable it in your hook, then you can get it to wrap at an arbitrary column:

```
(defun my-filcol-hook ()
  (visual-line-mode)
  (setq fill-column 80)
  (set-visual-wrap-column 80))
```

Make sure his code loads somewhere (such as your `.emacs` file).